# magento2 Saving attribute from quote_address to sales_order_address

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order, quote, custom-attributes

What i would like to do is to save a custom attribute in `quote_address` called: COC (Chamber of Commerce).
This attribute can be different from billing address and shipping address. That's why it's saved there.
It is getting saved in the `quote_address`.

Now what i want to do is to copy those values to `sales_order_address`.

Steps i tried:

- specify the fieldset like this:

  ```
  <fieldset id="sales_convert_order_address">
      <field name="coc">
          <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
      </field>
  </fieldset>
  ```
- Adding the attribute using a observer:

  ```
  $order->setCoc($quote->getCoc());
  ```

What i think is the problem is that `fieldset.xml` doens't get processed.
So it doesn't know that i want to save it to `sales_order_address`.

How can i set an attribute in `sales_order_address` using the observer event: `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: i am having this issue as well. "subdistrict" is saved to quote_address but not  in sales_order_address. i guess i have to go through sales_model_service_quote_submit_before

Comment: Menno and @DoniWibowo Do you find any solution for it?